# check whether password match or not in primefaces + javascript

Tags: java, javascript, jsf-2, primefaces

How can I check whether password match or not in primefaces + javascript?
I have used like this

```
function checkPass(){

var pass1 = document.getElementById('password');
var pass2 = document.getElementById('confirmPassword');
lert(pass2);
}
```

but getting null value! In primefaces I called like `onkeyup="checkPass(); return false;"`

Comment: Is there in fact an element in the dom with an id of "confirmPassword"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the string value we have to use following code in JSF Primefaces like,

```
var pass1 = document.getElementById('password_input'); 
var pass2 = document.getElementById('confirmPassword_input');
```

Answer (score 7):

I don't understand why are you using Primefaces and not take advantage of it's power...

There is a `password` tag in primefaces with a `match` attribute that matches the strings between two input passwords, also you can get a feedback if a password it's weaker or stronger:

```
<p:panel header="Match Mode">  
        <p:messages showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true"/>  

        <h:panelGrid columns="2" id="matchGrid">                     
            <h:outputLabel for="pwd1" value="Password 1: *" />  
            <p:password id="pwd1" value="#{passwordBean.password6}" feedback="true" match="pwd2" label="Password 1" required="true"/>  

            <h:outputLabel for="pwd2" value="Password 2: *" />  
            <p:password id="pwd2" value="#{passwordBean.password6}" feedback="false" label="Password 2" required="true"/>  
        </h:panelGrid>  

        <p:commandButton update="matchGrid" value="Save" />  
    </p:panel>
```

Please see this link: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/password.jsf .
Since you haven't specified you Primefaces version, I have to tell you that this solution is for Primefaces 3.

Comment: @lofain Yeah, I know that there was a bug regarding this in M3, but you can easily upgrade to M4 or RC1 (or even RC2-Snapshot it's stable - I've tried)

Comment: Since I had some issues on deploying my application in to GAE, while using M4, I returned to M3.Anyway I will try with RC1 or RC2. Thanks!

Comment: @lofain Good Luck! If you encounter problems don't hesitate to create here another question...if time is gentle to me, I'll help you with pleasure...

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
onkeyup="checkPass(this.value)"
```

And javascript code:

```
function checkPass(text) {
  var pass1 = document.getElementById('password');
  if (text == pass1.value) {
    alert('match');
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: But pass1 is getting null, even I have an id="password".

Comment: > Lofa: change ---> var pass1 = document.getElementById('password'); ---> to var pass1 = document.getElementById('password').value;